# PuLP Conditional Constraint Sum (Based on Variable)

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to optimize a problem where the decision variable (X) is a NxN binary matrix. I am finding trouble making one of the constraints of the problem work.

The ***first constraint*** implies that the sum of X in each row must be == 1. (Covered)

The ***second constraint*** (the one I cannot make to work) requires that for those columns where the diagonal is == 1, the sum of X must be >= 2. I have generated the following constraint in PuLP:

```
for j in W:
    prob +=  sum(X[i][j] for i in W if X[j][j] >= 1) >= 2
```

PuLP indicates the solution status is 'Infeasible'. ¿What am I getting wrong? ¿This constraint cannot be implemented in PuLP?

Essentially, an example solution matrix that covers the previous requirements would be:

```
[0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,1]
[0,0,0,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a **linear-programming framework** and therefore **only linear functions can be used**. *Arbitrary python-expressions* like:

- `if`
- `abs`
- `min`

are not passed to the solver, but are evaluated a-priori (the modelling-framework / solver do not see this) usually resulting in garbage.

These kind of things *must be linearized*. Some frameworks can provide some of those automatically, but that is a very tough task in general (as most linearizations are impossible without model-specific assumptions!).

([cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) for example supports re-formulation of `abs` and `min` while being compatible with some rule-set)

Here you will need to do this yourself.

If i understood the task correctly, it looks like:

- binary-matrix
- every row sums to 1
- every col sum is unconstrained, except for a column, where there is a 1 at the diagonal position -> then this column-sum has a lower-bound of 2

Example solution:

```
D!    D!

1  0  0  0   sum = 1 
1  0  0  0   sum = 1
0  0  1  0   sum = 1
0  0  1  0   sum = 1

sums
2  0  2  0
```

We can linearize the expression as:

```
for column in columns:
    (1-diag_elem_of_column) * bigM + sum(column) >= 2

    <-> 

    (1-diag_elem_of_column) * 2 + sum(column) >= 2
```

This is a classic big-M formulation, where there is some *binary indicator variable* (diagonal-element) activating/deactivating some linear expression using *some large constant big-M*. This large constant makes those approaches dependent on assumptions, but in your case this large constant does not need to be very large (and tightening is important for the integrality-gap -> better for the solver).

The idea is:

- Enforce `sum(column) >= 2` **except** when there is no diagonal-element hit
- When there is a diagonal-element hit -> (1-diag_elem_of_column) * 2 = 0 -> the sum is constrained to be >= 2 (as we need to get 2 non-zeros in the remaining variables)
- When there is no diagonal-element hit -> (1-diag_elem_of_column) * 2 = 2 >= 2 (sum of remaining elements is **free** -> no restriction as we already satisfied the minimum of 2)

Code-wise this could look like (untested):

```
# assumption: square-matrix
# assumption: X[row][col] storage-order

N = 5

for diag_element_index, col in enumerate(N):
  prob += (1 - X[diag_element_index][col]) * 2 + sum([X[row][col] for row in range(N)]) >= 2
```